# Different behaviour over WIFI and LAN-Ethernet when connecting via VPN

Tags: linux, wifi, vpn, ethernet, internet

I have some problems getting my internet connection working over the LAN, meanwhile over the WIFI, everything seems to work nicely with my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine.

First thing I do is connecting to my companiy's VPN in order to be able to access intranet and my machine. Login works fine, but then - if LAN is connected on my machine, I cannot access any websites except the local intranet websites. If I turn the LAN off, and use the WIFI connection, I can access both intranet sites as the web itself also.

I'm quite puzzled and don't know where to look for the problem - is this a common issue?

Additionally, I have set the proxy for the company to automatic at all time - which also I was not sure if needed.

Any hints and suggestions are more than welcome.

================================

EDIT: I could solve the problem by deactivating WIFI - now it seems to work just fine also with LAN. I leave the question open as I still do not understand what is happening!